# How to populate a timestamp field with current timestamp using Oracle Sql Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm reading a pipe delimited file with SQL Loader and want to populate a LAST_UPDATED field in the table I am populating.  My Control File looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE SampleFile.dat
REPLACE
INTO TABLE contact
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
ID, 
FIRST_NAME,
LAST_NAME,
EMAIL,
DEPARTMENT_ID,
LAST_UPDATED SYSTIMESTAMP
)
```

For the LAST_UPDATED field I've tried SYSTIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and neither work.  SYSDATE however works fine but doesn't give me the time of day.

I am brand new to SQL Loader so I really know very little about what it is or isn't capable of.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [ (precision) ]

```
select current_timestamp(3) from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
-----------------------------
10-JUL-04 19.11.12.686 +01:00
```

To do this in SQLLDR, you will need to use EXPRESSION in the CTL file so that SQLLDR knows to treat the call as SQL.

Replace:

```
LAST_UPDATED SYSTIMESTAMP
```

with:

```
LAST_UPDATED EXPRESSION "current_timestamp(3)"
```

Comment: Still doesn't like it.  Gives me this error:

    SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 17.
    Expecting "," or ")", found "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".
    LAST_UPDATED CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)

Comment: Can you try doing:

LAST_UPDATED EXPRESSION "SELECT current_timestamp(3) from dual"
OR
LAST_UPDATED EXPRESSION "current_timestamp(3)"

Comment: Hehe, okay, that works great : LAST_UPDATED EXPRESSION "current_timestamp(3)", the select from dual option didn't for some reason.  However, turns out that SYSDATE would have worked fine.  I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I accepted RC's answer because ultimately he answered what I was asking but my unfamiliarity with some of Oracle's tools led me to make this more difficult than it needed to be.

I was trying to get SQL*Loader to record a timestamp instead of just a date.  When I used SYSDATE, and then did a select on the table it was only listing the the date (05-AUG-09).

Then, I tried RC's method (in the comments) and it worked.  However, still, when I did a select on the table I got the same date format.  Then it occurred to me it could just be truncating the remainder for display purposes.  So then I did a:

```
select TO_CHAR(LAST_UPDATED,'MMDDYYYY:HH24:MI:SS') from contact;
```

And it then displayed everything.  Then I went back to the control file and changed it back to SYSDATE and ran the same query and sure enough, the HH:MI:SS was there and accurate.

This is all being done in SqlDeveloper.  I don't know why it defaults to this behavior.  Also what threw me off are the following two statements in sqldeveloper.

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL; //returns a full date and time 

SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL; // returns only a date
```

Comment: SYSDATE returns a DATE data type (but that includes hours minutes and seconds). CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns a TIMESTAMP data type which goes down to fractional seconds (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i53219).
Both these have internal representations (eg DATE is held as 7 bytes) and the client chooses how to display them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the table defined default you can use:

```
ROWDATE EXPRESSION "DEFAULT"
```

Answer (score -1):

In Sql Developer run: 
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

and then check it with
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL

Comment: This won't work - you're not changing the date at all and you're altering a _different_ session.