# How to insert name of file and modified time using batch/shell script and sql loader

Tags: shell, batch-file, sql-loader

I have a requirement to insert bulk data into an Oracle database from a CSV file. Now table columns specs match those of the CSV file's header with the exception of three additional fields in database:

1. A Primary Key field (for which a simple SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL is called)
2. A field for the name of the CSV file
3. A field for the last modified date+time of the file

The following stack question address an extra column issue, but the solution is pretty easy because it used Oracle sysdate which is internally available. I need to pass a parameter from either batch script/shell script.

[Insert actual date time in a row with SQL*loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267153/insert-actual-date-time-in-a-row-with-sqlloader)

Can PARFILE help here somehow?

My other alternative would be to do the whole task in two steps by writing a small java code:

1. Use SQL Loader for bulk upload leaving out data for the filename and
   modified time
2. And then run a separate update statement to populate the newly
   created rows

But I'm looking for something which will get the job done in one shot. Any advice??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm affraid it's not possible with sqlldr alone.
There is no tools for this in sqlldr.
You'd need some sort of script or a program to dynamically create a .ctl file for each load.
Here is a bash script to help you get started:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
readonly MY_FILENAME=$1
readonly DB_BUF_TABLE=$2
readonly SQLLDR_CTL="LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
APPEND INTO TABLE $DB_BUF_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'(
  filename \"$MY_FILE_NAME\",
  col_foo,
  col_bar
)"

echo "$SQLLDR_CTL" > "loader.ctl"
sqlldr control=loader.ctl parfile=loader.par data="$MY_FILENAME"
sqlldrReturnValue=$?
```

You'd needsome locking with this.. or path separation for concurrent loads to be sure sqlldr starts with proper ctl file